# How to pass variables to PHP using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I've searched this site for the answer that fits this scenario but couldn't.

Here's the Function which returns results from the database of all the users:

```
function management_active() {

include('db.php');
include('connect.php');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE activ_status='1'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxModal();" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="View Profile"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>';
            echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="editAjaxModal();" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a>';
            echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="delAjaxModal();" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Remove User"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';   

    global $user_link;
    $user_link = $row['activ_key'];

}
```

}

This function displays all of the users that are active in a table, I then have buttons which allow a user to view the user's profiles in a modal. The modal needs to load the user's data via AJAX.

Here's the JQUERY Script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAjaxModal()
{
    jQuery('#show-modal').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "data/ajax-profile.php",
            data: "u=<?php echo $key; ?>",
            success: function(response)
            {
                jQuery('#show-modal .modal-body').html(response);
            }
        });
    }, 800);
}
</script>
```

And here's the PHP file which returns the results to the AJAX Call:

```
$user_link = $_GET['u'];

if ($user_link==="$user_link") {

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE activ_key='$user_link'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo $row['username'];
        echo $row['fname'];
        echo $row['lname'];

    }

} else {
    echo '
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>

        <strong>Oh Snap!</strong> Something went terribly wrong.
    </div>
    ';   
}
```

The issue is that I can't seem to get the correct user's details, it always outputs the very last row in the database table.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're echoing the key at the bottom, you need to pass the key while looping

```
echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxModal(\'' . $row["activ_key"] . '\');" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="View Profile"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>';
```

then require the key in the JS functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAjaxModal(key)
{
    jQuery('#show-modal').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "data/ajax-profile.php",
            data: "u="+key,
            success: function(response)
            {
                jQuery('#show-modal .modal-body').html(response);
            }
        });
    }, 800);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would personally recommend that 1.) dont encode variables into function calls - pull the arguments from attributes on the element, 2.) dont use event handler attributes like `onclick` instead use jQuery to do `$('selector').on('click', showAjaxModal)`.

Comment: While we're at it, I'd suggest a ton of other changes to the original code as well....1) don't use echo to output html blocks, 2) escape the string before using it in a query 3) use a PHP framework, 4)... :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated! I'm still learning PHP (I'm a design guy) so I indeed do have to learn all of the best practices.